# How to make the value (to be read) of form field widget in yii2 different from what users see in the input text box

Tags: forms, input, yii2, widget, field

I am modifying a system already developed in yii2 framework.

There is a functionality where a user views a list of customers and against each record there is a button for editing. When clicked, a form is displayed with values automatically filled in for the customer against whom the 'edit' button was clicked.
Now, the is a field for address which is filled with the database record id of the address instead of the name of the location. The id is a number, and the field was validated to check that the value is a number when the 'Update' button is clicked.

**Problem**:
Instead of filling the field with the number (i.e the id) I am requested by users to fill that field with the name of the location which is not a number and therefore will violate the validation rule.

I want to be able to make the value of the input field (i.e the value attribute) to be the id -a number so that it does not violate the set rule - but display the name of the location in the text input so that the users have a readable 'value' to look at.

How can I achieve this?

**CODE**
There was this:

```php
<div class="col-sm-6"> 
    <?= $form->field($model, 'village')->widget(\kartik\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
        'options' => ['value' =>$model->village],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

The value in **$model->village** is the id of the village. This is what users do not want.

I tried doing this:

```php
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <?php 
  $villageName = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT village_name FROM v_village WHERE id='.$model->village)->queryOne();
  $streetName = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT street FROM v_street WHERE street_id='.$model->street)->queryOne();
 
  ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'village')->widget(\kartik\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
        'options' => ['value' => $villageName['village'], 'id' => $model->village],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

But that violates the validation rule and the error I get says 'Village must be a number'

Answer (score 0):

You have to set data array of your select.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <?php 
  $villageName = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT village_name FROM v_village WHERE id='.$model->village)->queryOne();
  $streetName = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT street FROM v_street WHERE street_id='.$model->street)->queryOne();
 
  ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'village')->widget(\kartik\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => [$model->village => $villageName['village']],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true //are you sure you want to be able to clear the option? If you save it empty the query above will break
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what is your purpose, but if you have only this value you can just show it like text.

If you want to be able to change the village you code must be like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'village')->widget(\kartik\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Village::find()->all(), 'id', 'village_name'),
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true //are you sure you want to be able to clear the option? If you save it empty the query above will break
    ],
]); ?>
```

Also you can remove the query and set data like this:

```
'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Village::find()->where(['id' => $model->village])->all(), 'id', 'village_name')
```